# jQuery get multiple id attribute on click

Tags: jquery, onclick, attr

I'm trying to get the id attr from different onclicks.

Here is the html I have.

```
<div id="name-1"> 
    <a href="#" class="view">
<div> 

<div id="name-2"> 
    <a href="#" class="view">
<div> 

<p>Name: <span class='name'></span></p>

<script>
$(".view").click(function() {
    var id = $(".view").closest("div").attr("id");
    $('.name').html(id);    
}); 
</script>
```

When I click the first view I see "name-1" however when I click the second view nothing happens. Also, when I click the second name it shows "name-1". I know this is probably easy to solve but it's friday so I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
var id = $(".view").closest("div").attr("id");
```

to

```
var id = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
```

Right now your current code is looking at the first `.view` on the page rather than the `.view` whose click event was triggered.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are using the `view` class selector to get the closest id. So, it looks for the first available `view` and gets you the id for first `DIV`.

Consider using `$(this)` to get the closest id for the clicked element.

```
$(".view").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
});
```

Don't forget to read this article on "**jQuery this**": http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/